# Anonymous user's can't views/download files uploaded via file field

Tags: 7, users, files

I have a node with a File field and i am using public file system. I have uploaded a file via File field and checked the mark "display" in the list of attached files to node, but still, anonymous user's can't even view it (also they can't download it), till i check this permission:

[image]

But i think it's security vulnerability. Is drupal 7 file access system broken? Or am i missing something?

**Manage display page**

[image]

Comment: You should not give anonymouos to bypass file access control. Could you post a screenshot of the "manage display" page for the content type?

Comment: Yeah, sure check the updated post.

Comment: Permissions on sites/default/files are ok? Link to download file appear on node view?

Comment: Permission on folder files is 775, no, link doesn't appear. When i try to open the file directly it throws me - access denied.

Comment: And if you view the node using admin? Are you sure that the file is a "public" and not "private" file?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure it's public. When i view node as user (with id 1) i see the file and able to download it, but anonymous doesn't even see it.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out! I have uploaded a .rar file, so drupal wouldn't recognize this as existed file types e.g. audio, image, document. I had to go in **admin/structure/file-types/manage/document**

And add mimetypes for .rar and .zip extension:

```
application/rar
application/zip
```

Then just reuploaded file and gave anonymous user's permission:

```
Document: Download any files
```